# NodeJS App 'Module Not Found' when run from Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I'm currently in the process of containerizing my App. Part of the App is a NodeJS Express Backend.
It works without any issues when I run it on my console with `node index.js` or `nodemon index.js`.

[image]

Inside the `middlewares/index.js` I do import `authJwt.js` and `verifySignup.js` via `require('./verifySignup)` and `require('./authJwt)`.

This works unsurprisingly well when I run my app from the console. However If i build my docker-image using the following Dockerfile-Code:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14

# Working Directoy
WORKDIR /app

ENV FILE_UPLOADS="./files/uploads"
ENV FILE_UPLOADS_PART="./files/uploads_part"
ENV PORT=3001
ENV DB_HOST="localhost"
ENV DB_USER="root"
ENV DB_PASSDWORD="root_password"
ENV DB_NAME="upload_db"
ENV SECRET_KEY="bezkoder-secret-key"

# Copy Needed Files for Dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock

# Install with YARN
RUN yarn install

# Copy Source Files
COPY ./ /app

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

When I run the Image it immediately terminates. Looking at the logs I find the following error:

```bsh
$ docker logs 031241ce227a
yarn run v1.22.5
$ node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './verifySignUp'
Require stack:
- /app/middleware/middleware.js
- /app/routes/auth.routes.js
- /app/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/middleware/middleware.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1075:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1096:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/app/middleware/middleware.js',
    '/app/routes/auth.routes.js',
    '/app/index.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I then exported my docker-image using `docker export adoring_kowalevski > contents.tar` to look at the filesystem inside the image, but everything is where it should be.

In a desperate attempt I hoped, that the issue might occur because I have multiple `index.js` in different folders, so I changed the names of all except the one in the root directory, but issue persisted. This is why in the error-log there is a `middleware/middleware.js`, it was after renaming the `middleware/index.js`.

Edit:
I tried using [rfr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfr) to change my references from `require('../middleware')` to `rfr('middleware')`. It still workds from console but still not inside the container. So it seems that the issue doesn't occur because of the relative file paths.

Comment: if that is your structure "Inside the middlewares/index.js I do import authJwt.js and verifySignup.js via require('./verifySignup) and require('./authJwt)."

you should use '../verifySignup'

Comment: Can you post your package.json too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I'm stupid (somewhat).

The import inside `middleware/index.js` looked like this `require('./verifySignUp')`.
If we look at the file `verifySignup.js` inside the `middleware` Folder we can see, that it is named without the capital 'U'.

**Why did it still work from console?**
Inside `verifySignup.js` is the following piece of code:

```js
module.exports = {
    authJwt,
    verifySignUp
};
```

Here it is written with capital 'U'. This means that running `node index.js` from the console only cared about whatever was written in the `module.exports` and not the actual Filename, however when running inside Docker, the Filename matters.

Renaming the file from `verifySignup.js` to `verifySignUp.js` solved my problems.

Comment: That didference comes from os. inside the docker in unix file names differ with case but in windows not.